# formated data in database present in web browser

Tags: node.js

I have setup a huge database after searched web and grabed data for a long time.
I hope to present these data in web/web browser.
Just wonder if there is any nodejs framework that similar with joomla/wordpress(cms) can display the formated data.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several nodeJS CMS like :

- [Calipso](http://calip.so/)
- [keystonejs](http://keystonejs.com/)
- [Ghost](https://ghost.org/)
- ....

Ghost is a beautiful blogging platform, and has a lot of community support including a theme marketplace. It started with a very successful kickstarter campaign, and launched a few months ago. It is limited by design, and totally focused around the publishing workflow they have built.

KeystoneJS is a more flexible cms / framework which can be used to create anything from a blog to a sophisticated, data-driven website. There's a [demo site](http://demo.keystonejs.com/) (with a simple Bootstrap theme) you can use as the basis for your own blog [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone-demo), and a more complex site built for the [Sydney Javascript](http://sydjs.com) meet up [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/sydjs-site) which you can also use as a reference.

I'd say make your decision based on whether you want a focused, polished publishing system or a more flexible cms, as well as how comfortable you are customising and working with each platform.

Ghost is probably the easiest to get up and running with, as long as it has all the features you'll need.

Another thing to consider is where you will host your blog - Ghost offers [their own hosting solution](https://ghost.org/pricing/), while KeystoneJS supports [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) which is free for 1 dyno. Again, you should have a look at both and decide which you are more comfortable with.

Comment: which one can create a donwload site like cnet download.com easily, my future site is not a download site but structure is very similar